# Check Phone Directory (phone to Linux connection)

Tags: python, linux, directory, copy

I'm writing a script that copies the images taken by my phone camera to the Pictures folder on my Linux machine.

```
import shutil
from os.path import isdir

source_directory = "mtp://SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_98897a384e484c5433/Phone/DCIM/Camera/"
destination_directory = "/home/lemons/Pictures/"

def main():       
    if isdir(source_directory):    # If the phone is plugged in correctly
        print("Phone is plugged in correctly.")
    else:
        print("Error: {0} not found! Please make sure the phone is plugged in.".format(source_directory))
    
    if isdir(destination_directory):    # Check if the target directory exists
        print("Target directory is present.")
    else:
        print("Error: {0} not found!".format(destination_directory))
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that when I look for the source directory in my file explorer, I'm dealing with a different directory naming format: `mpt://[insert phone device name]/Phone/DCIM/Cmaera/"`. When I run the script, if says that the source directory is not found. How do I check if this directory exists via `isdir()` when I run the script while my phone is unlocked?

Comment: Find the actual mountpoint from the command line and use that. If theres is no actual mountpoint, and your file-browser uses a special plugin to interact with the phone, try finding out how your browser does it ...

Comment: I didn't find a mountpoint that appears to be a mobile device. Btw: my distro uses Thunar as the file browser.